# Add up text of parent/children with data frame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, vectorization, apply

I have a few CSV files which can have thousands of rows. Each row has an index and and text like this:

```
+--------+--------------+-
| index  | text         | 
+--------+--------------+
|      6 |        text1 | 
|  6 (1) |        text2 | 
|  6 (2) |        text3 | 
|      7 |        text4 | 
|  7 (1) |        text5 |
```

if we consider 6 as parent of 6 (1) and 6 (2) and 7 as parent of 7(1) I need to:

- add text of 6(1) and 6(2) to 6, and add text of 6 to 6(1) and 6(2)
- add text of 7(1) to 7 and text of 7 to 7(1)

so final csv would be something like this:

```
+--------+------------------------+-
| index  | text                   | 
+--------+------------------------+
|      6 |    text1 text2 text2   | 
|  6 (1) |  text1 text2           | 
|  6 (2) |  text1 text3           | 
|      7 |   text4 text5          | 
|  7 (1) |  text4   text5         |
```

I know how to do it with loops but I'm looking for a fast and optimized way. maybe apply or Vectorization?

Thank you

Comment: So the index column contains text values '6(1)' for example?

Comment: @Mohammad, Yes correct but there is an space between 6 and (1) like 6 (1)